# How to do nginx rewrite on a specific query string pattern?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

We are getting lots of traffic to our main site in following patterns.  The parameters is different everything this is messing up my cache.  I need to do redirect:

These redirect to `/?lang=zh-hans`

```
/?lang=zh-hans&category=26%2C27&full=1&mo=9&yr=2022&id=1800312749
/?lang=zh-hans&category=26%2C27&full=1&mo=8&yr=2022&id=111871000
/?lang=zh-hans&id=1930613962&category=26%2C27&full=1&mo=10&yr=2022
/?lang=zh-hans&category=26%2C27&full=1&mo=08&yr=2022&id=1205387849
```

These redirect to `/?lang=zh-hant`

```
/?lang=zh-hant&category=26%2C27&full=1&mo=9&yr=2022&id=1800312749
/?lang=zh-hant&category=26%2C27&full=1&mo=8&yr=2022&id=111871000
/?lang=zh-hant&id=1930613962&category=26%2C27&full=1&mo=10&yr=2022
/?lang=zh-hant&category=26%2C27&full=1&mo=08&yr=2022&id=1205387849
```

To avoid the complexity, I just need to do it on the root path.

This is what I have tried on nginx, but it's not working.

```
rewrite ^/?lang=zh-hans&category=.+ /?lang=zh-hans permanent;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to redirect all requests with parameters starting with `/?lang=zh-hant…`  to the `/?lang=zh-hant`, and requests with parameters starting with `/?lang=zh-hans…`  to the `/?lang=zh-hans`, omitting other GET parameters. This can be done somehow like this:

```
http {

  … skipped …
  
  map $request_uri $redirect {
    "~^\/\?lang=zh-hans&.*$"   /?lang=zh-hans; 
    "~^\/\?lang=zh-hant&.*$"   /?lang=zh-hant;
  }

  server { 

    if ($redirect) {
        return 301 $redirect;
    }

  … skipped …
  
  }
}
```

Here, in `map` section we tell `nginx` to check if [$request_uri](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_uri) is **starting** with `?lang=zh-hans&` or `?lang=zh-hant&` substring and set corresponding value to the `$redirect` variable.
Then in `server` section we tell `nginx` to check if `$redirect` exists and if so, return 301 redirect with location from that variable.

Please note, that tis will work only if `lang` parameter is the first in `$request_uri`, i.e. request to
`/?lang=zh-hant&category=26%2C27&full=1` will be redirected, but
`/?category=26%2C27&lang=zh-hant&full=1` will be processed *without* redirect

Comment: Thanks @theKorzh.  My server is CWP and it has lots of website installed.  I am afraid putting the map command outside of the server block may affect lots of websites. Is there anyway to put this into the location block?  But map is not allowed there.

Comment: `map` itself doing nothing but creating new variable with value, based on conditions. You can find some more information in [documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map).
It is safe to use map outside `server` or `location` block if you use unique and understandable names for that variables. For example, you can declare `$mysite_com_redirect` variable in `map` section and, if then you'll use it only in `server` section for `mysite.com`, no other `server` sections will not be affected.

Comment: Anyway, you can avoid `map` by using `if` directive inside `server` block. In example:

      `if ($request_uri ~ ^\/\?lang=zh-hans&.*$) {
   return 301 /?lang=zh-hans;
      }`

It will make config a bit less clear, but it will work.